# Find and replicate onclick behavior in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html

On this page https://www.betbrain.co.uk/next-matches/ there is a button with the text "Advanced". Its code when you inspect the page:

```
<a data-nmtab="nmAdvancedFiltersTab" class="MMLink" href="#" title="Filter 
the next matches with advanced tools">Advanced<span class="Hideable"> 
Filters</span></a>
```

The button, when clicked, shows some filter-options. I have been told that its attached function was set with an addEventListener call. So I searched for addEventListener calls in the elements windows and found nothing that has any indication of being related to the behavior of the button when clicked. I then set an event listener breakpoint for mouse clicks and that lead me to this function (but located in a local file called "index" in the source tab):

```
add: function(a, c, d, e, g) {
            var h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s;
            if (!(a.nodeType === 3 || a.nodeType === 8 || !c || !d || !(h = f._data(a)))) {
                d.handler && (p = d,
                d = p.handler,
                g = p.selector),
                d.guid || (d.guid = f.guid++),
                j = h.events,
                j || (h.events = j = {}),
                i = h.handle,
                i || (h.handle = i = function(a) {
                    return typeof f != "undefined" && (!a || f.event.triggered !== a.type) ? f.event.dispatch.apply(i.elem, arguments) : b
                }
                ,
                i.elem = a),
                c = f.trim(I(c)).split(" ");
                for (k = 0; k < c.length; k++) {
                    l = A.exec(c[k]) || [],
                    m = l[1],
                    n = (l[2] || "").split(".").sort(),
                    s = f.event.special[m] || {},
                    m = (g ? s.delegateType : s.bindType) || m,
                    s = f.event.special[m] || {},
                    o = f.extend({
                        type: m,
                        origType: l[1],
                        data: e,
                        handler: d,
                        guid: d.guid,
                        selector: g,
                        quick: g && G(g),
                        namespace: n.join(".")
                    }, p),
                    r = j[m];
                    if (!r) {
                        r = j[m] = [],
                        r.delegateCount = 0;
                        if (!s.setup || s.setup.call(a, e, n, i) === !1)
                            a.addEventListener ? a.addEventListener(m, i, !1) : a.attachEvent && a.attachEvent("on" + m, i)
                    }
                    s.add && (s.add.call(a, o),
                    o.handler.guid || (o.handler.guid = d.guid)),
                    g ? r.splice(r.delegateCount++, 0, o) : r.push(o),
                    f.event.global[m] = !0
                }
                a = null
            }
        },
```

which quite simply just confuses me. Finally, if it even is possible to find the code for its behavior, as if it had an onclick attribute, can I execute this code on the page without clicking the button myself?

Answer (score 0):

How about running this?

```
document.querySelectorAll('a[data-nmtab="nmAdvancedFiltersTab"]')[0].click()
```

Comment: Uh nice it does the job regarding the last part of the question! Thanks. But still, how can I find the code that is being executed and attached to the button?

Comment: The click handler is being attached to the containinf `ul` element with this IIFE:
(function (selector, event, callback, ctx) {
      jQuery(ctx.el).on(event, selector, function () {
        callback.apply(ctx, [
        ].slice.call(arguments));
      });
    }(selector, event, callback, this));
 in `commonJsLibs201901220841.js` file, inside of `attachEvents` function.
It's hard for me to investigate further and tell from provided context who and with what parameters calls it.
What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks man! What I am trying to achieve is just to be able to run the code being executed, by the button, from the console :) Also, how did you figure that out?' Ahh that was probably why it was referring me to that function in the OP. But is it not possible to find the exact javascript code that is being executed when the button is clicked?

Comment: Just looked at attached event handlers and walked little bit through code.
You can find it in chrome DevTools in the `Elements` tab, by selecting element that you are interested in, and see it's: Styles, Computed, `Event Listeners` etc.
In firefox you can find links to handlers right on according elements inside the `Inspector`. They're marked as `event` button, which is expandable and has functions and links to their sources.

Comment: Yea wasn't that what I wrote in my post? Not asking to be rude, but I might then need to reword it if it can be misunderstood. The part "I then set an event listener breakpoint for mouse clicks and that lead me to this function". Anyways, but what about "But is it not possible to find the exact javascript code that is being executed when the button is clicked?"? :)